# Disable scrolling in a UITextView while avoiding both bouncing to top and invisibility of text at the present location for ios

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I've tried a lot of things but couldn't come up with a solution. Any words of thought can help me evaluate on this. I made a full view DrawBoard class which is inherited from a UITextView class.When the switch on the view controller is on the user can type and scroll, when it is off the user can draw on the Drawboard.

```
@IBAction func changeSwitch(sender: UISwitch) {
        if sender.on{
            drawBoard.setNeedsDisplay()
            drawBoard.scrollEnabled = true
            drawBoard.editable = true
            drawBoard.selectable = true
            drawBoard.switchBool = false

        }else if !sender.on {
            drawBoard.switchBool=true
            let a:CGPoint = drawBoard.contentOffset
            drawBoard.scrollEnabled = false
            drawBoard.setContentOffset(a, animated: false)
            drawBoard.editable = false
            drawBoard.selectable=false
        }

    }
```

It updates the scrolling but `scrollEnabled= false` just saves the text that is in the first page range of the textview so that it scrolls to the top automatically and disable the scrolling there.Then when I do the setContentOffset the drawable view of the background is visible and it draws on the right place of the textview. However the  text that should be on top of it is not visible. This only happens when the switch button is set to off while I am out of the first page's range.How do I also make the text at that range visible?

Sorry if it's a really easy question I'm new to programming and got stuck for a considerable amount of time for this.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the content size of the UIScrollView.

Like this:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
```

"Content Size" determines the size of scrollable content, if it's not large enough to cover new views, you won't be able to see it in your scroll view.

Comment: I don't have a ScrollView, I just have a custom UITextView class DrawBoard and I don't want to restrict its height. What I'm having issues is the scrollEnabled=false because it automatically bounces the scroller of the UITextView to top. ScrollEnabled hinders setContentOffSet (that ı used in the above code) and the text below the CGPoint a is not shown in the textView although the content is in the right place. I hope the problem is a bit clearer now. Thank you for your response. Would you recommend me to edit the above question with this clarification in case there is a misunderstanding?